# How to set up an interrupt for a PWM pin

Tags: raspbian, python-3, interrupts

I have a GPIO pin set up as a PWM. I would like to set up an interrupt every time the PWM signal goes high. Is there any way of doing it?

I tried mixing the pigpiod library and rpi library, but when I get the PWM to work through pigpiod and then  use GPIO.wait_for_edge, it seems to overwrite the PWM functionality.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I am aware the RPi.GPIO module only allows interrupts and wait for edge on GPIO which are in mode INPUT.  That means you can't use those features on a GPIO outputting PWM (e.g. a GPIO in mode PWM or mode OUTPUT).

pigpio will allow alerts and wait for edge on such GPIO.

Comment: Thank you, I'm thinking of an alternative solution

Comment: I tried using callback(user_gpio, edge, func), it seems to work but for some reason it get's out of the while loop, I've edited the post to show the code

Comment: Actually I'll start a new question